# C# Application Send Email. ERROR [Sending Mail Failed.]

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, hotmail

I am building a application in C# using .net framework 4.5 in Visual studio 2012 RC.

I am sending email to my account for the sake of application feedback and questions.
This is the small application.

Few days ago my application was running well. and i was receiving emails.

Right now i got exception pops up as "sending mail failed."

I tried many tweaks but no effect. my account is not asking for reactivate. I turn off my firewall as well .. no work at all same exception. I am attaching a exception details. Too.
 Please have a look on it.

Please Help me. I have done too much google.

**My Code is**

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
try
{
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));
    message.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom);

    //Attachment attachment = new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    message.Subject = "McFarlane Industries Product's Registration Request";
    message.Body = packageRequestContent();
    message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    //message.Attachments.Add(attachment);


    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 587; // Gmail works on this port
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailFrom, mailFromPass);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = nc;
    client.Send(message);
    MessageBox.Show("Thank you for Registring...!", "Register Notification!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Request not submitted. " + ex.Message);
}
```

**The Exception Details are:**

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Failure sending mail.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       at McFarlaneIndustriesPOSnamespace.Registration.sendMailUsingHotmail(String mailFrom, String mailFromPass, String mailTo) in e:\Works\McFarlane Industries\McFarlane Industries Point of Sale Source Code\McFarlaneIndustries\Registration.cs:line 73
       at McFarlaneIndustriesPOSnamespace.Registration.buttonSendRegistrationRequest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Works\McFarlane Industries\McFarlane Industries Point of Sale Source Code\McFarlaneIndustries\Registration.cs:line 47
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at McFarlaneIndustriesPOSnamespace.Program.Main() in e:\Works\McFarlane Industries\McFarlane Industries Point of Sale Source Code\McFarlaneIndustries\Program.cs:line 20
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       HResult=-2146232800
       Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
            at System.Net.BufferedReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)
            at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response)
            at System.Net.Mail.StartTlsCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            HResult=-2147467259
            Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
            Source=System
            ErrorCode=10054
            NativeErrorCode=10054
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: I use very similar code to yours and it works. You should log on to the account in Gmail and try to send a mail manually.

Comment: -2146233088 is 80131500 in hex.  If you search on that error code, there's tons of hits around communication issues like firewalls etc... http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/error-code-80131500/d24818da-7ba6-4e48-bfe9-6db321e3d5d6

Comment: Please show the exception text.

Comment: @Micheal Yes i login to the gmail account but same problem.

Comment: @byanmac Yes i turn off the firewall but same exception.

Comment: Check 'mailFrom', 'mailFromPass' for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

I would try logging into the Hotmail/Gmail account using a web interface.  Sometimes Hotmail will randomly lock your account and make you reset the password; especially if you're using the account to send bulk emails.

Comment: The stacktrace says hotmail, but the code says smtp.gmail.com

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hm.  Still, I can't think of what else would cause this, other than a locked account.

Comment: @Blorgbeard. Yes i have corrected the mistake. actually i am using hotmail too. but both of them same error. Anyway i have corrected the mistake. i was entering hte hotmail from Mail address. My Mistake.